# MongoDB slow - memory usage very high

Tags: mongodb

I have a 5 note replicaset mongoDB - 1 primary, 3 secondaries and 1 arbiter.

I am using mong version 4.2.3

Sizes:

```
“dataSize” : 688.4161271536723,
“indexes” : 177,
“indexSize” : 108.41889953613281
```

My Primary is very slow - each command from the shell takes a long time to return.

Memory usage seems very high, and looks like mongodb is consuming more than 50% of the RAM:

```
# free -lh
              total        used       free         shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          188Gi       187Gi       473Mi        56Mi       740Mi       868Mi
Low:          188Gi       188Gi       473Mi
High:            0B          0B          0B
Swap:         191Gi       117Gi        74Gi


------------------------------------------------------------------
Top Memory Consuming Process Using ps command
------------------------------------------------------------------
  PID  PPID %MEM %CPU CMD
  311 49145 97.8  498 mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
23818 23801  0.0  3.8 /bin/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
23162 23145  0.0  8.4 /usr/bin/cadvisor -logtostderr
25796 25793  0.0  0.4 postgres: checkpointer
23501 23484  0.0  1.0 /postgres_exporter
24490 24473  0.0  0.1 grafana-server --homepath=/usr/share/grafana --config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini --packaging=docker cfg:default.log.mode=console
```

top:

```
PID    USER     PR  NI    VIRT   RES    SHR S   %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  311 systemd+  20   0  313.9g 184.6g   2432 S 151.7  97.9  26229:09 mongod
23818 nobody    20   0   11.3g 150084  17988 S  20.7   0.1   8523:47 prometheus
23162 root      20   0   12.7g  93948   5964 S  65.5   0.0  18702:22 cadvisor
```

serverStatus memeory shows this:

```
octopusrs0:PRIMARY> db.serverStatus().mem
{
        "bits" : 64,
        "resident" : 189097,
        "virtual" : 321404,
        "supported" : true
}
octopusrs0:PRIMARY> db.serverStatus().tcmalloc.tcmalloc.formattedString
------------------------------------------------
MALLOC:   218206510816 (208097.9 MiB) Bytes in use by application
MALLOC: +  96926863360 (92436.7 MiB) Bytes in page heap freelist
MALLOC: +   3944588576 ( 3761.9 MiB) Bytes in central cache freelist
MALLOC: +       134144 (    0.1 MiB) Bytes in transfer cache freelist
MALLOC: +    713330688 (  680.3 MiB) Bytes in thread cache freelists
MALLOC: +   1200750592 ( 1145.1 MiB) Bytes in malloc metadata
MALLOC:   ------------
MALLOC: = 320992178176 (306122.0 MiB) Actual memory used (physical + swap)
MALLOC: +  13979086848 (13331.5 MiB) Bytes released to OS (aka unmapped)
MALLOC:   ------------
MALLOC: = 334971265024 (319453.5 MiB) Virtual address space used
MALLOC:
MALLOC:        9420092              Spans in use
MALLOC:            234              Thread heaps in use
MALLOC:           4096              Tcmalloc page size
------------------------------------------------
Call ReleaseFreeMemory() to release freelist memory to the OS (via madvise()).
Bytes released to the OS take up virtual address space but no physical memory.
```

How can I detrmine what is causing this high memory consumption, and what can I do to return to nornal memory consumption?

Thanks,
Tamar

Comment: Have you tried something like [currentOp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) to identify the heavy workload?

Comment: How can I tell from the output of "currentOp" if the query is heavy? I can't find in the output an indication for CPU/memory consumption...

Comment: As a very simple and naive approach, often `currentOpTime` is the first field we check if we suspect there is a long running query jamming the DB.